# Validate total amount of fields

Tags: laravel

I have 5 inputs and the total amount should be between 1 and 10000 but I am not exactly sure how to do in Laravel. This how my service looks like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use App\Services\Interfaces\TransactionInterface;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class CashTransaction implements TransactionInterface
{
    protected array $inputs = [];

    public function __construct(array $inputs)
    {
        unset($inputs['_token']);
        $this->inputs = $inputs;
    }

    public function validate(Request $request): array
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'one_dollar' => 'nullable|integer|min:0',
            'five_dollars' => 'nullable|integer|min:0',
            'ten_dollars' => 'nullable|integer|min:0',
            'fifty_dollars' => 'nullable|integer|min:0',
            'hundred_dollars' => 'nullable|integer|min:0',
            'total_amount' => 'lte:' . $this->amount()
        ]);

        return $validator->errors()->all();
    }

    public function amount(): float
    {
        $total = 0;

        foreach ($this->inputs as $input => $value) {
            $total += $value;
        }

        return (float)number_format($total, 2);
    }

    public function inputs(): array
    {
        return $this->inputs;
    }
}
```

`total_amount` doesn't exist in the request so I can guess that this is the main problem but still don't get it how to validate it.

Comment: In this case will be better to make a custom rule. It will calculate sum of inputs and validate it and will return the validation message too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I validate the sum of the values in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70170256/how-can-i-validate-the-sum-of-the-values-in-laravel)